# How to send Google Talk (XMPP) messages with only gmail Adress?

Tags: android, xmpp, google-talk

i searched this but i couldn't find any solution ...

I want to develop an application in android , in this application you have a friend list. i want to you can send messages with XMPP to your friends, and get messages with XMPP through Google Talk Server . For  be able to do this, i created a instance application  about sending Google Talk (Xmpp) messages between two Android devices [with this link](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/)  and [this link](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000119). i used asmack.jar for this and now i can send messages between 2 device.  But Problem is this ;

i have two gmail addresses , for example foo@gmail.com  and   bar@gmail.com .

for chat between 2 devices and send message from first one to second recipient , i have to write "bar@gmail.com/Smack014GAB5B....." as recipent address . if i only write "bar@gmail.com" as recipient , i can't send it ...

Question is , how can i send message to recipient without "Smack014GAB5B..." extension after "/" ?

Any help would be great ...

Comment: Did you add foo to bar roster and vice versa?

Comment: What do you mean adding to roster ? Do this means adding Google+ friend list ? Can't device comminucate without being in roster in other gmail's friend list ?

Comment: Google Talk has some spam prevention restrictions, so yes, better to add both parties in their friend's list. On your self-hosted xmpp server you can operate without it.

Comment: when they added roster list to each other's  , can i communicate only with gmail address ? is this required for chat that adding "\Smack0AGAGAA.." to mail address , or is this a problem about my app ?

Comment: I added two gmail to each other's Google+ friend List . I can see as a roster in logcat other one. but still , i have to write an extension to recipient gmail to be able to send message to other device . if i write only gmail address , i get message in mail.google.com as a hangout message ..  any advice would be great ...

Comment: Both parties must be connected with "Available" status, otherwise messages will be stored as mail. You need to send `<presence />` to show that you available.

Comment: how can device be available ?  can't i comminucate with other devices when they are not available ? i want to send messages to devices in anytime.. so they can see it with my application.

Comment: Why you not read my second sentence?

Comment: so u say , if mails added rosters , and if one's presence is available , one device can send message to other one with gmail address ? No "\Smack0sfasdf" extension ?

Comment: Check it and describe problem if any, maybe you forgot something else. But when all requirements are met - you will be able to use only address without resource.

Comment: i did [this example](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000119) . but it says about using Smack API , do this mean use asmack.jar or much more ? how can i use Smack API ? Maybe problem is this ....